# Value not being passed to a dynamically created onclick function

Tags: javascript, html, google-apps-script, onclick

I have a button `Add Filter` which I'm creating dynamically when the value in the dropdown list `Choose table` changes. I added the onclick atttribute for `Add Filter` in the JavaScript and I want to pass an argument to it. However, when I pass an argument by `filterButton.onclick=addFilter(db);` it executes addFilter() even before I click it even though the value of `db` is passed correctly. And if I give `filterButton.onclick=addFilter();` and try to access db as `this.db` OR `db` as a global variable, it prints undefined and null respectively.

What I am trying to do is, execute `addFilter(db)` when I click on the button `Add Filter` and it should get the value of the selected db, that is, the selected dropdown list. What am I doing wrong?

Here's the [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/8mk9evo0/)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <body>


    <script>

 function get_ids(db){

//return ids;
 }

function clearDivs(){

    //Clears view    
    }
function chooseTable(db) {

 clearDivs();

 var div = document.getElementById("table"); 

var ids=get_ids(db);
var parentElement = document.getElementById('ids');

//adding checkboxes (removed here for simplicity)

 var filter = document.getElementById('filter');
 var filterButton=document.createElement('input');
 filterButton.type='button';
 filterButton.value='Add Filter';
 filterButton.onclick=addFilter(db);
 filter.appendChild(filterButton);


 }

 function addFilter(db){
 window.alert(db);     
 }  

 </script>
  <center>

<div id="main1">

<div>

Choose Table:<br/>

<select id="table" name="table" onchange="chooseTable(this.value)">

     <option name="choice" value=""></option>
    <option name="choice1" value="hr.employee">Employees</option>
    <option name="choice2" value="account.account">Accounts</option>
    <option name="choice3" value="hr.holidays">Holidays</option>
    <option name="choice4" value="account.voucher">Account Vouchers</option>
  </select>
</div>
</div>  
</center>
<div id="ids"></div>

<center>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<div id="filter"></div>

<br/><br/><br/><br/>

<input type="button" id="clicking" value="Get result" onclick="getResults();"/>
<div id="check1"></div>
</center>

  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

One option you can try is:

```js
...
// filterButton.onclick=addFilter(db);
filterButton.onclick = (function(current_db) {
                           return function() {
                               addFilter(current_db);
                           }     
                       })(db);
...
```

<kbd>[JSFiddle demo](https://jsfiddle.net/8mk9evo0/6/)</kbd>